# Background- size cover esque with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hey so I'm remaking a website for a music label and was doing some research and really intrugied by but is done on the artist pages on def jam music website 
http://www.defjam.com/artists/big-sean/

they have so sort of carousel gallery but its responsive to always fit the screen until you scroll down is there anyway to do this with Bootstraps carousel?

Does anyone have any idea how they do this or seen a plugin to do so???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) with media queries or a fluid layout will get your where you need to go.

Check out an example [here](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/).

Its implemenation is super simple, for example:

js:

```
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

html:

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Will get you something identical to the live example listed above.